# Docker: Database is not being created

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm running my `docker-compose.yml` file and when I run
`docker-compose --verbose up --build` I get error:
`Host 'websites_backend_1.websites_default' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server` 
and that's because the database isn't being built correctly. When I look at the logs for the db I see:

```
{"log":"2020-07-17T20:47:32.048295Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-07-17T20:47:32.048692809Z"}
{"log":"2020-07-17T20:47:32.048574Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-07-17T20:47:32.048985478Z"}
{"log":"2020-07-17T20:47:32.053617Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-07-17T20:47:32.054070073Z"}
{"log":"2020-07-17T20:47:32.074099Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.21'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-07-17T20:47:32.07428149Z"}
{"log":"2020-07-17T20:57:31.584660Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user \u003cvia user signal\u003e. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.21).\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-07-17T20:57:31.584841262Z"}
{"log":"2020-07-17T20:57:32.156022Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.21)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-07-17T20:57:32.156200018Z"}
```

My `./mysql` dir from `- "./mysql:/var/lib/mysql"` is empty

`docker container ls` produces

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
6b418818c780        websites_frontend   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   49 seconds ago      Up 48 seconds       0.0.0.0:3002->3000/tcp              websites_frontend_1
389d86543214        websites_backend    "python3 manage.py r…"   50 seconds ago      Up 49 seconds       0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp              websites_backend_1
03ab9131cf37        mysql:latest        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   24 minutes ago      Up 50 seconds       0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   websites_db_1
d03eb504da0f        memcached           "memcached '-m 64'"      About an hour ago   Up 50 seconds       0.0.0.0:11211->11211/tcp            websites_cache_1
```

When I do `docker exec -it websites_db_1 bash`
I can do `show databases` but dont see `my_database`

Locally my docker project is working but on my server its not.

why is this happening? I cant figure it out.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app/backend
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
      - cache
    links:
      - db
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
       #One-way volume to use node_modules from inside image
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3002:3000"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    depends_on:
      - backend
    tty: true
    command: npm start


  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    volumes:
      - "./mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
      - "./.data/conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_database
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root

  cache:
    image: memcached
    ports:
      - "11211:11211"
    expose:
      - "11211"
    entrypoint:
      - memcached
      - -m 64

volumes:
    mysql: {}
```

Comment: Have you tried running without `command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password`?

Comment: Maybe your server is trying to connect to the database before it's up? Try adding a delay.

Comment: @ajtrichards I tried it but the same error happened

Comment: @ParthShah how do i add a delay?

Comment: Really depends but `command: sh -c "sleep 15 && python3...`

Comment: Looks like you're having a permissions issue. Can you try these troubleshooting steps? https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/275#issuecomment-292208567

Answer (score 0):

I've been there, its easy but **NOT RECOMENDED ON PRODUCTION**, it occurs that when you run your Mysql container (db in your case) for the first time it creates some files on .mysql because you defined that on the volumes:

```
volumes:
      - "./mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
      - "./.data/conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d"
```

So when you run it again the files are there and it docker skips the creation of database assuming that it already has info.

So to fix it just delete the contents of .mysql folder on your machine and re-run your container.

to easy that process run

## NEVER (NEVER) RUN IN PRODUCTION

```
docker-compose rm -fv;
rm -rf .mysql/*
```

But remember dont run in production.